# Why do HTTP GET and POST requests pass parameters to the server in different ways (body vs. URI)?

Tags: http, post, parameters, get

I know that typically, GET requests pass relevant parameters by appending query strings to the URI.  POST requests pass parameters by inserting them into the request body.

I also know that it is considered bad practice to pass GET parameters into the request body, but that is not an explanation as to *why* this behavior was initially implemented. As far as I can tell, the main difference between GET and POST requests is more or less semantic.  That is, I can generally assume GET is safe and POST is not, which helps me understand that I can cache GET results, and allow GET to call multiple times without worrying that I am going to mess something up server-side. This does not explain why there is a different implementation for passing parameters. Would it have been a bad idea to have GET be semantically equivalent to the way that it is used now but use the request body to pass parameters instead of the URI?  Similarly, was there a compelling historical reason for the designers of HTTP to divide how GET and POST stored parameters (in such a seemingly arbitrary way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might help to re frame this a bit to not look at these as parameters, but take a step back.

Ultimately the purpose of the `GET` request is to ask a server for the representation of a given URI. The fact that the URI has things that are 'parameters' or 'variable' is kind of irrelevant here.

The idea of the `GET` request is, give me the thing at this URI. The fact that there are some mechanisms to dynamically build up these URIs is not important.

You can do the exact same thing with POST. Any URI that you can `GET`, you could send a `POST` request to. So these URI variables can also exist for `POST`.

So on a high level, this is what the requests are for:

```
GET - Return the representation at the given URI
PUT - Replace the representation at the given URI
DELETE - Remove the resource at the given URI
```

Looking at these operations as *something you do at the given URI* it starts to make sense that `GET` doesn't have a request body. If the purpose of the request is simply 'give me the thing at this uri', there's no real reason to *also* have a body.

Likewise, it doesn't make that much sense for a `PUT` request to respond with a body. The purpose of `PUT` is to replace whatever is at the given URI with the request body. The caller only really needs to know if the operation succeeded or not, so a HTTP status code is enough.

For `DELETE` neither the request *or* response body really makes sense. All you need to know is there is a URI, and you are calling the DELETE operation, which succeeds or fails.

So what about `POST`? `POST` is really a bit of a catch-all that is used for basically 'anything else'. You're not explicitly replacing, removing or retrieving a resource, but rather you are doing 'some arbitrary operation', like doing an RPC call or creating a new resource in a collection.

Unlike `GET`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`, the meaning of `POST` is much more loose.

```
POST - Do an arbitrary operation at the given URI.
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! So ultimately, the separation between query parameters and HTTP body allows us to further cement the semantic difference implied by, say, GET vs. POST?  So I should be thinking of query parameters as extensions to a URI (further specifying the resource) and as the body as some source of data that is not necessarily associated with a server resource?

Comment: Yeah the full URL is the locator to the resource, and that does include query parameters. What the semantic meaning is of the request/response body and how this pertains the resource at the given URI depends on the request method, ranging from 'this is the representation of the of the URI for GET or PUT' to 'There's no implicit semantic meaning' for 'POST".

Answer (score 1):

Data in the URL can be linked to, bookmarked and easily shared.

Data in the request body can be *big*, and easily include things which are not text (like file attachments).

Comment: Makes sense to me, thanks!  So what I am getting from this is that there are practical limitations to query parameters vs. body data, which probably has to do largely with the semantic differences Evert touched on in his answer.